# Nested SELECT with REGEXP in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

this what I want to do, get the book titles that start with 'the' and then 3 to 8 characters and then 'CONCAT' theme with a specific text.
I tried this but it did not work:

```
select concat((select title from books where title REGEXP '^the.{3,8}$'), '.....') from books;
```

This is what I get:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat((select title from books where title REGEXP '^the.{3,8}$'), '.....') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
| The Circle.....                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you please give a sample result?

Comment: your regex `^the.{3,8}$` suggests that selected `title` of `books` table should start with `the` and then  end with `3-8` characters. Is this what you want ?

Comment: I added the output I get

Comment: yes @SALEH this what I want then I want to add a specific text or word to each title using CONCAT

Answer (score 3):

As I don't know what you want as Output, something like that would work if Mysql version >= 5.5 :

```
SELECT concat(title, '....') as My_title
FROM book
WHERE title REGEXP '^the.{3,8}$'
```

Comment: Hi, I want to get all of the book titles that start with 'the' and then 3 to 8 characters and then 'CONCAT' theme -or add to each title- with a specific text

Comment: Thanks alot that really worked but still I would like to know how to use nested select in practical life

Comment: In practical life try to avoid a nested select. In 70% case use Inner Join/Left Join or if you need to 'pivot' the result a good use of a case/when will be better than a subquery in a select